# how to add icons beside app_name in android

Tags: android

I need a help regarding an issue in android...

I have an application with a name "Example" which i declared it in string`<string name="app_name">Example</string>`and now i want to add some buttons/icons like search beside my app_name...

on emulator it should look in this format:   app_name-------------------------icon1--icon2--icon3

hope my question is clear at least up to some extent

can anyone help me how to achieve this i'm new to android clear explanation will be more helpful please help me................

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to add icon with application name in phone gallery?

you modify your manifest file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/here is your image name"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</application>
```

you simply chage application icon

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is making menu items `showAsAction` and have an icon.

Here's an example of how a menu item would look like in the menu's xml:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

`app:showAsAction` will make it show beside the title (outside of the menu).

`android:icon` will give it an icon.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Menu icon by App name]

If you put too many and force them to show with `always`, it would show like this:

[image: Menu icons by App name]

Answer (score 0):

Just set these icons in the drawable folder. I prefer it in the medium quality. Then just add these images in your main.xml

```
<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/ImageButton01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/album_icon" 
android:background="@drawable/round_button" />
```